# Forcing a type's fields to not be optional

Tags: typescript, typescript2.2

Given a type with optional properties, including a nested reference to another type with optional properties (such as itself):

```
type Foo = {
    fieldA?: string,
    fieldB?: number,
    fieldDeep?: Foo,
};
```

is there a way to produce a version of that type with all properties now non-optional:

```
type RequiredFoo = {
    fieldA: string,
    fieldB: number,
    fieldDeep: RequiredFoo,
};
```

This type would essentially be the reverse of a deep form of Partial, which is doable:

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>
};
```

I figured out a strange trick do this shallow-ly for instances of a type:

```
function required<T>(obj: Partial<T>): { [P in keyof T]: T[P] } {
    return obj as any;
} 

const requiredFoo: {
    fieldA: string,
    fieldB: number,
    fieldDeep: Foo,
} = required({} as Foo);
```

but I can't find a way to express this type recursively, mainly because I cannot express the function above as an actual type definition---the reason it works at all is because of the `obj: Partial<T>` parameter, perhaps because it infers that any optional parameters are due to obj being Partial, rather than because of the object itself.

Comment: This is quite interesting, but my guess is you are trying to solve the wrong problem because this is quite intention-prune. i.e. it is more likely to require some properties in a type while keeping others optional. My 2cents.

Do you have a specific use case you can share? I'd like to learn what application can this apply.

Comment: Try this `type Required<T> = T extends object ? { [P in keyof T]-?: NonNullable<T[P]>; } : T;`

Comment: Let me know, if this works, I will post as answer...

Comment: Typescript has updated since and this is now sort of built-in with `Required<T>`, which is defined in the standard lib. However, this (and yours I believe) are not `DeepRequired`. I will accept an answer if you provide one that works recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now expressible using the `Required<T>` built-in:

```
type DeepRequired<T> = Required<{ [P in keyof T]: DeepRequired<T[P]> }>;
```